# Operator overloading and printing

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am having difficulty with a test I am trying to run on a backend utility.

```
int main(){
    Status_List s_list;

    s_list.add_status("Blind", 2);
    s_list.add_status("Stun", 5);
    s_list.add_status("Deaf", 3);
    s_list.add_status("Weak", 4);
    print_status(s_list);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        --s_list;
        print_status(s_list);
    }

    return 0;
}

void print_status(Status_List s_list){
    for(int i = 0; i < s_list.status.size(); ++i){
        std::cout << s_list.status[i]->get_eff() << ", " << s_list.status[i]->get_dur() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I believe the difficult I am having is in relation to this utility:

```
Status_List& Status_List::operator--(){
    int i = 0;

    while(i < status.size()){
        if(status[i]->get_dur() <= 1)
            rem_status(i);
        else{
            status[i]->dec();
            ++i;
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

Status_List Status_List::operator--(int){
    Status_List tmp(*this);
    operator--();
    return tmp;
}
```

Output is correct until I reach the first decrement. After some testing, I've found that the decrement function ends, but once the print_status() function is called inside the for loop, I get a segmentation fault, leading me to believe that somehow I've changed the bounds of the vector.

A member of class Status_List:
`std::vector<Status *> status;`

A member of class Status:
`void dec() {duration--;}`

At this stage of the game, none of the members should have activated the rem_status() function.

Is my operator overload correct, and I'm barking up the wrong tree, or is something off in the operator--() function?

EDIT:
The rem_status() function is shown here. Since the output never indicates below 2 on the return of get_dur(), this function should never have been called before the segfault.

```
void Status_List::rem_status(int index){
    Status * stat = status[index];
    status.erase(status.begin() + index);
    delete stat;
}
```

Comment: You need to show all of the details of your `Status_List` class. A [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) would be best.

Comment: I don't need to copy lines in here that are irrelevant. I have verified constructor accuracy through my own testing, and the destructor has yet to be called. Other members of the class are not related, and have been proven (by my excluding them in tests) not to have an effect upon the result.

Comment: I would disagree. The behavior of the `rem_status()` function is quite relevant to your question, hence the suggestion to provide a self-contained example.

Comment: Well, since the output from testing indicates that get_dur() doesn't drop below 2 in any of the cases, I don't think it's going to have any bearing, but you can view the edit if you want.

Comment: @ciphermagi I've tried to reproduce the problem, using the details you provided and some guesses... However I didn't found the segmention fault (tried with valgrind too). What I've done is on http://ideone.com/7xNSYV . I might be wrong in some of the guesses, so please review and provide more details.

Comment: It's pretty similar, except for the level of visibility that each member has. Many of the members are private, and the print function is a friend for the purposes of debugging. I have been playing with it in the interim, and if I take everything out except the print statements, for some reason I'm still getting the segfault.

Comment: well, the problem must be somewhere in between your code and my code

Comment: I've got it down to just the call. `std::cout << s_list.status[i]->get_eff() << ", " << s_list.status[i]->get_dur() << std::endl;` inside of the main function works just fine, no matter how many times I call it, but if I call from a different function (`print_status()`) it segfaults on the first element in the second call.

Comment: @ciphermagi Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? or perhaps a memory-checking tool like valgrind?